# Python parsing XLS with images

Tags: python, parsing, xls

Have a problem with extracting images from xls files. There a lot of variants to parse xls using python (some libraries I have found there http://python-excel.org - xlrd, xlwt). But have hot found any information about extracting images from xls files without exporting to the other format.

For example, if i parse document with xlrd, it defines a cell with image as an empy str.